# $f(x-y)=f(x)f(y)-f(a-x)f(a+y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, functional-equations

> If $f(x-y)=f(x)f(y)-f(a-x)f(a+y), f(0)=1$
> Show
> a) $f(a)=0  $
> b) $f(t)=f(-t)$

a) falls out easily setting $y=0, x=a$

I can get really close but I can't quite do this. I would appreciate a hint more than a full solution.

Setting $x=t, y=t$
$$f(0)=f(t)^2-f(a-t)f(a+t)$$
and $x=-t,y=-t$
$$f(0)=f(-t)^2-f(a+t)(a-t)$$

Then subtracting we find $f(t)= \pm f(-t)$. How do I eliminate the negative solution, or is there a better approach altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1) x=t, y=0$

$f(t)=f(t) f(0)-f(a-t) f(a)=f(t) f(0)$

because $ f(a)=0$

$2) x=0, y=t$

$f(-t)=f(t) f(0)-f(a-t) f(a)=f(t) f(0)$

From 1) and 2)
$\Rightarrow \quad f(t)=f(-t)$

Comment: Great, but I think the first part is unnecessary, its done after you set x=0 y=t right?